# How to handle "JNI WARNING : 0x44f81e80 is not a valid JNI reference"

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am facing crash with

```
JNI WARNING : 0x44f81e80 is not a valid JNI reference, in Ldalvik/system/NativeStart;. run()v (GetObjectClass)
```

I found some post saying use NewWeakGlobalRef instead NewGlobalRef. But I am looking for validation in my code. All I want to know is is there any `JNI` api using which I can check whether given `jobject` is valid `JNI` reference or not? Something like unsigned

`char isValid = (env)IsValidJNIRef(myjobject);`

Using that isValid's value I can put some condition to handle system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the ref type of a jobject referred to by the obj argument using:

```
jobjectRefType GetObjectRefType(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj);
```

Which returns one of the following enumerated values defined as a `jobjectRefType`:

```
JNIInvalidRefType = 0,
JNILocalRefType = 1,
JNIGlobalRefType = 2,
JNIWeakGlobalRefType = 3
```

Note that you can't use this on deleted refs - it is not specified what value the `GetObjectRefType` will return for a deleted ref.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#objreftype

Comment: Actually, having said that, I'm not sure if GetObjectRefType is implemented in the Android NDK and I couldn't find the documentation online anywhere to confirm.